# How to grep to find all instances of a Java method call using a reference?

Tags: grep

I am trying the following query, but without success

```
    grep -nr "[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+\(\)" .
```

So, according to my logic, a method call would be one or more alphanumeric characters

```
   [[:alnum:]]+
```

followed by a dot

```
   \.
```

followed by one or more alphanumeric characters

```
    [[:alnum:]]+
```

followed by paranthesis (for void return type only)

```
    \(\)
```

But this query isn't working. How to write such a query?

Comment: A method call may not have dot `.` if calling method is part of the same class.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, you are right. I am currently interested in those instances that are called using a reference. I have modified the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` provides several types of regex syntax.
Your pattern is written is the extended syntax and works with `-E`
`extended-regexp` has an easier/better syntax, and `perl-regexp` is, well, quite powerful.

- -E, --extended-regexp
- -F, --fixed-strings
- -G, --basic-regexp    (the default)
- -P, --perl-regexp

---

```
grep -nrE "[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+\(\)" .
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "\+" instead of "+" otherwise it'll directly match the character "+".

Comment: Thanks for this. Why is it that I don't need to use backslash *, but need to use backslash + ?

Comment: Just a guess: * is more fundamental than \+ as you can much more easily implement the latter with the former (and the theoretical papers on regular expressions all use *). The symbol * would have in grep from version one, but \+ was probably added in later versions of grep as a convenience. It would have been escaped so as not to break existing regexps that already used + as a literal match.